# EntityFrameworkCore Task.WhenAll() A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to read data from database. For this I create a query and queryhandler classes

QueryHandler

```
public class OrderGetQueryHandler: IQueryHandler<OrderGetQuery, OrderDTO>
    {
        private readonly GoodWillWebDbContext _context;
        private readonly IQueryDispatcher _queryDispatcher;

        public OrderGetQueryHandler(GoodWillWebDbContext context, IQueryDispatcher queryDispatcher)
        {
            _context = context;
            _queryDispatcher = queryDispatcher;
        }

        private bool CheckPartnerBlock(BlockTypes blockType, decimal debtOverdue, bool payOff)
        {
            if (blockType == BlockTypes.Block)
                return true;
            if (blockType == BlockTypes.NotBlock)
                return false;
            if (blockType == BlockTypes.PreliminaryPayment)
                return payOff;

            return debtOverdue <= 0;
        }

        public async Task<OrderDTO> HandleAsync(OrderGetQuery query)
        {
            var order = await _context.Orders.FindAsync(query.OrderID);
            if (order != null)
            {
                var getCustomerTask = _context.Partners.FindAsync(order.CustomerID).AsTask();
                var getCuratorTask = _context.Users.FindAsync(order.CuratorID).AsTask();
                var getPaymentTask = _context.Payments.OrderByDescending(x => x.PaymentID).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.CustomerID == order.CustomerID);
                var getOrderLinesTask =
                    _queryDispatcher.HandleAsync<OrderLinesGetQuery, OrderLineDTO[]>(
                        new OrderLinesGetQuery(query.OrderID));

                await Task.WhenAll(getCustomerTask, getCuratorTask, getOrderLinesTask, getPaymentTask);

                var priceRange = await _context.PriceRanges.FindAsync(getCustomerTask.Result.PriceRangeID);
                return new OrderDTO
                    (
                        order.OrderID,
                        getCustomerTask.Result.Name,
                        getOrderLinesTask.Result,
                        order.CustomerID,
                        order.OrderStateID,
                        order.CanDelete,
                        order.CreationDate,
                        getPaymentTask.Result.DebtBank,
                        getPaymentTask.Result.DebtOverdue,
                        this.CheckPartnerBlock(getCustomerTask.Result.BlockTypeID, getPaymentTask.Result.DebtOverdue, order.PayOff),
                        priceRange.Name,
                        order.ReservationDate,
                        Mapper.Convert<DeliveryInfoDTO, BaseEntities.Entities.Sales.Order>(order)
                    );
            }
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
    }
```

this queryhandler i use in ASP.NET WEB Application. My startup class is

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        services.AddDbContext<GoodWillWebDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connection), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

        services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<OrdersGetQuery, BaseEntities.DTO.Sales.Order.OrderDTO[]>, OrdersGetQueryHandler>();
        services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<OrderGetQuery, Sales.Queries.DTO.Order.OrderDTO>, OrderGetQueryHandler>();

        services.AddScoped<ICommandDispatcher, CommandDispatcher>();
        services.AddScoped<IQueryDispatcher, QueryDispatcher>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
}
```

I set ServiceLifetime.Transient for my context, but I still get an exception: InvalidOperationException A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're running multiple operations on the context without waiting for the previous ones to end, which EF doesn't like:

```
var getCustomerTask = _context.Partners.FindAsync(order.CustomerID).AsTask();
var getCuratorTask = _context.Users.FindAsync(order.CuratorID).AsTask();
var getPaymentTask = _context.Payments.OrderByDescending(x => x.PaymentID).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.CustomerID == order.CustomerID);
```

Either make these call sync or use the `await` keyword.